# ValueError: Cannot convert <PyTime:9/11/2017 1:35:02 AM> to Excel

Tags: python, excel

I am getting this error while running the below code

```
current_time=MailItem.ReceivedTime
ws.cell(row=1, column=1).value = current_time
```

Error from running code:

```
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 294, in value
    self._bind_value(value)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\cell.py", line 201, in _bind_value
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
ValueError: Cannot convert <PyTime:9/11/2017 1:35:02 AM> to Excel
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should manually convert PyTime to string or to Python date/time type. Probably you could use

`time.ctime(int(current_time))` or

`time.strftime("%#c", time.localtime(int(current_time)))`.

See also http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/PyTime.html